# Can I have more than 250 columns in the result of a PostgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql

Note that PostgreSQL website [mentions](http://www.postgresql.org/about/) that it has a limit on number of columns between 250-1600 columns depending on column types.

Scenario:

Say I have data in **17** tables each table having around **100** columns. All are joinable through primary keys. **Would it be okay if I select all these columns in a single select statement?** The query would be pretty complex but can be programmatically generated. The reason for doing this is to get denormalised data to populate a web page. Please do not ask why though :)

Quite obviously if I do `create table table1 as (<the complex select statement>)`, I will be hitting the limit mentioned in the website. But do simple queries also face the same restriction?

I could probably find this out by doing the exercise myself. In the next few days I probably will. However, if someone has an idea about this and the problems I might face by doing a single query, please share the knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't find definitive documentation to back this up, but I have
>   received the following error using JDBC on Postgresql 9.1 before.
>
> ```
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: target lists can have at most 1664 entries
> ```
>
> As I say though, I can't find the documentation for that so it may
>   vary by release.

I've found the confirmation.  The maximum is 1664.

This is one of the metrics that is available for confirmation in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SQL_SIZING table.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SQL_SIZING 
WHERE SIZING_NAME = 'MAXIMUM COLUMNS IN SELECT';
```